# sprintf code consuming lot of space (embedded)

Tags: c, embedded, printf

I have written the following function for sprintf

```
#include <reg52.h>

char output_arr[7];

void print_to_arr(float val)
{
  int integer, fractional, temp = 0, i, ni = 2;
  float fract;

  integer = (int)val;

  fract = val - (float)integer;
  fract = fract *1000;
  fractional = (int)fract;

  for(i=0; i<=2; i++)
  {
    temp = integer%10;
    integer = integer/10;
    output_arr[ni - i] = temp+48;
  }
  temp = 0;

  output_arr[3] = '.';

  for(i=0; i<=2; i++)
  {
    temp = fractional%10;
    fractional = fractional/10;
    output_arr[(ni+4) - i] = temp+48;
  }
  temp = 0;
}
```

and for this the code size is

```
Program Size: data=36.0 xdata=0 code=1112
```

Can anyone please hep me with how to reduce the code size to the minimal possible vale?

Comment: I compiled with `gcc -Os` on amd64 and it comes to 111 bytes of instruction text.  What compiler and options are you using to get 1111 (bytes, presumably)?

Comment: I am using keil C
and here it what it displays
Build target 'Target 1'
compiling sprintf_test.c...
linking...
Program Size: data=36.0 xdata=0 code=1112
"sprintf_test" - 0 Error(s), 0 Warning(s).

Comment: Have you tried `OPTIMIZE(11, SIZE)`?  See here: http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_optimize.htm

Comment: Not looking at your actual algorithm, some optimizaion is in in removing redundant elements: do not initialize temp as it gets its value in the loop. No need to set temp to zero after the loops. Remove variable ni and replace with constant.

Comment: It is evident from the reference to "xdata" that you are probably using an 8 bit 8051 architecture device.  If that is the case, it is worth making that clear in the question (not the comments) - "*embedded*" alone does not imply any particular constraints, but being 8 bit and having no FPU is critical to an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 3):

Performing floating point operations on a device with no floating point hardware, and especially an 8 bit device will itself introduce a significant amount of code (every operation must be supported by a function rather than a single instruction).  Most stdio implementations for constrained embedded targets have an option to omit floating point support for exactly that reason.

Even without floating-point, on an 8 bit target integer modulo (`%`) and divide (`/`) are often expensive. In this case 8051 only has an 8 bit divide operation, so for larger types divide is synthesized from multiple instructions.

If you really must have floating point support, then the following may have a small impact on size.  The changes include minimisation of floating point operations, eradication of unnecessary variables, the use of initialisation rather than assignment of the variable initial values, and removal of the loop invariant `ni + 4` operation.  These may have no impact, or they may make it easier for the optimiser to generate smaller code - they may make things worse; you'll have to experiment.

```
void print_to_arr(float val)
{
  int integer = (int)val ;
  int fractional = (int)(val * 1000.0f) - (integer * 1000) ;
  int i ;

  for( i = 0; i < 3; i++, integer /= 10 )
  {
    output_arr[2 - i] = integer % 10 + '0' ;
  }

  output_arr[3] = '.';

  for( i = 0; i < 3; i++, fractional /= 10 )
  {
    output_arr[6 - i] = (fractional % 10) + '0' ;
  }
}
```

Note that the implementation does not round the final fractional digit, and fails completely for negative values.  Fixing these issues requires yet more code.